# Extension Field of $e^{\frac{i\pi}{5}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

> Let $w = \cos\frac{2\pi}{10}+ i \sin\frac{2\pi}{10}$.
>
> Let $K=\mathbb Q(w^2)$ and $L=\mathbb Q(w)$. Then

1. $[L:\mathbb Q] = 10$
2. $[L:K] = 2$
3. $[K:\mathbb Q] = 4$
4. $L = K$

Now, once we know the value of $w$, we can find the degree of the extension field, but how to find the value of $w$? or can we find the degrees without finding the $w$ value? please explain..

Comment: $\cos(\frac{\pi}{5})=\frac{1}{4}(1+\sqrt5)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$w=e^{i\pi /5}$ and thus $X^5-1$ is an annihilator polynomial (you don't need anything else !). Since $$X^5-1=(X-1)(X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1)$$
and that $X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1$ is irreducible (why ?) $$[L:\mathbb Q]=4.$$

For similar reason, $[K:\mathbb Q]=4$, and thus $K=L$ (why ?).

Comment: Sorry...I cannot get you..will you please explain little more briefly..why we are using annihilator polynomial here?

Comment: You need the minimal polynomial (since $[ \mathbb Q(\alpha ),\mathbb Q]=\deg\min(\alpha ,\mathbb Q)$). You know that the minimal polynomial divide any annihilator polynomial. Therefore, if you can find an irreducible polynomial that divide $X^5-1$, you won ! (which is precisely $X^4+...+1$. But why is it really irreducible ?) @SamChristopher

Comment: yes..its cyclotomic polynomial of degree 4(even) so it is irreducible over Q.

Comment: Then what about L = K.?

Comment: Because $K\subset L$ and both has same degree.

Comment: Heads up the number being extended by is a tenth root of unity, not a fifth root of unity. You have your annihilator polynomial wrong.

Comment: I'm wrong it's $X^5+1$ (but not $X^{10}-1$). But since $X=-1$ is a root, it's doesn't change the result. @Vik78